# How to upgrade the Ember version in an Ember CLI application?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Assuming I created this Ember application last week:

```
ember new shop
cd shop
ember install:addon ember-cli-scaffold
ember g scaffold product name:string
```

The console tells me that this application uses Ember 1.10.0:

[image: Screenshot of the JavaScript Console.]

How can I upgrade this Ember application to Ember version 1.11.0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax has been updated to:

`bower install ember#2.0.0 --save-dev --save-exact`

Comment: they don't use bower anymore I don't think

Answer (score 3):

@Sukima's answer will work fine, but you can also use the `ember-cli` command:

```
ember install:bower ember#<version>
```

In your case, upgrading to Ember 1.11.0 would look like this:

```
ember install:bower ember#1.11.0
```

Source: http://www.ember-cli.com/#using-ember-cli

Comment: As of EmberCli 1.13.8 this command has been removed in favor of `bower install <packageName> --save-dev --save-exact`.

Answer (score 2):

Update the version in your `bower.json` file and run

```
bower install
```

Comment: This is correct method according to the official guides at https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/tutorial/ember-cli/. Also note if the version of ember-data in package.json is behind the latest, update the version number and then run npm install.

Answer (score 2):

From ember-cli 2.11 version, ember is served from npm package, so you need to update `ember-source` version number in `package.json`

```
"ember-source": "~2.11.0"
```