# How to upgrade my Ember application?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

What is the recommended way to upgrade Ember from version 1.13.8 to version 2.3?

I have seen an example on this link [How to upgrade the Ember version in an Ember CLI application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29328355/how-to-upgrade-the-ember-version-in-an-ember-cli-application).

Is that the only thing that I have to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to fully upgrade your application and dependencies, I recommend following the instructions on the [ember-cli release post](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases/tag/v2.3.0-beta.1).

If you only want to upgrade Ember.js itself, the version in `bower.js` is indeed the only thing you need to change.

Comment: getting an error bower ENOGIT git is not installed or not in the path when running the bower install. Currently I'm running it on my application path. Then, which path should I run it? Sorry. Confused here.

Comment: That's strange, it should work. Sorry, but that's very specific to your machine and environment. Check that your `$PATH` is correct maybe?